# Community deplyment issues related to componentName

Tags: change-set, community-cloud, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I am facing this error when I want to deploy my community site to another partial prod, the ERROR MESSAGE IS 'The value for `componentName c:layout` in `partnerportalv31/views/home1.json` isn't valid. Check the value and try again.'
To put you in the context, what I did is:

- Created a changeset containing all the components, objects, apex classes used in my community site (This deployment went successful passing all the tests)
- then I've created another changeset that has my Site.com, and then I got this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, whenever you face this kind of insignificant error try to re-check your change set to see if you are missing a dependency and clone your change set and add those dependencies to it then upload again.